# How to find patents for endoscopic capsules?

Tags: prior-art

There is an incredibly useful device that is used in [capsule endoscopy](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsule_endoscopy).

I am curious to know whether such a device is already patented, as they cannot be purchased and neither do I have physical access to a medical professional which does.

The device features a miniature camera, LED lights and a storage device, all fitted in a compact capsule casing, small enough to safely pass through your digestive tract.

How to search such patents any quick methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal keyword search of "capsule endoscopy" in Google patent will provide you good source of patent list. On quick reference I found ["Recent Patents on Wireless Capsule Endoscopy"](http://catai.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/ec-patents.pdf) which will be of more useful to you.

Comment: Well, I have to admit I had no prior knowledge that querying for patents was this easy--quite embarrassing. Thank you for redacting the question and improving it's relevancy.